# Recoll: Can I safely exclude ~/.recoll from a full system backup?

Tags: 20.04, backup, recoll

I am using recoll. It seems to me that it builds its (very large) index database into `~/.recoll` (not sure what exactly is part of that). Since I can rebuild the database if need be, I would like to not include stuff that I can recover into a full system backup.

Does `~/.recoll` contain anything important or can I safely exclude it from a full system backup?

Comment: alternatively put recoll somewhere else and make a soft link to it, back it up separately if you want to.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.

As a matter of fact, I let it start with option `-c` at `/mnt/usb-C/C-gegevens/workeRmachine/.recoll` which also has the xapian-database. The alias I use is stored in `.bashrc`, namely:

```
alias recoll='recoll -c /mnt/usb-C/C-gegevens/workeRmachine/.recoll'
```

(Do use `>> .bashrc`!!!)

In the `.recoll/recoll.conf` I used:

```
"topdirs=/mnt/usb-C/C-gegevens/workeRmachine/Documents      /mnt/usb-C/C-gegevens/workeRmachine/Pictures"
```

And I regularly keep the user directory safe by issuing:

```
rm ~/.recoll
```